# The cast to value type 'Int32' failed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, lambda

I have the following code. I'm getting error:

> The cast to value type 'System.Int32' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type.

```
var productItem =   from sales 
                      in db.Sales_inv_details
                  select new { 
                           sales.Sales_Invoices.Customer.Cust_Id, 
                           sales.Sales_Invoices.Customer.Customer_Name,         
                           sales.Sales_Invoices.Employe.Emp_Name, 
                           sales.Sales_Invoices.Employe.Emp_code,
                           sales.Sales_Invoices.Date_invoice, 
                           sales.Item.Item_ID, 
                           sales.Qty, 
                           sales.Qty_Price, 
                           sales.Item.Item_Name, 
                           sales.Item.Item_Code, 
                           Unit_Measure = sales.Item.TBL_Unit_Measure.Code,
                           sales.Sales_Invoices.Descrption, 
                           sales.disc };

productItem = productItem
  .Where(x => (x.Date_invoice >= model.Fromdate & x.Date_invoice <= (model.Todate)));

productItem = productItem
  .Where(x => (x.Emp_code == model.Emp_code));
```

Comment: what variable is null? Did you debug it?

Comment: How does your model look like?

Comment: I can't even find my null variable i am getting this error when using
foreach (var item in productItem)

Comment: but i guess it's Description and Unit_Measure

Comment: When debugging, go through the items in productItem and you will find the null variable. Just focus

Comment: if hard to find, try with single where condition then add more where condition it will easy to find in which where you get error

Comment: yes as i said it's Description and Unit_Measure both are null

Comment: @HassenCh. if the error is happening in the materializer, you won't see that - it will error when reading the row, before you ever see the partially constructed object. A stack trace would help, of course. There are no casts shown in the code, so: I strongly suspect it hasn't left the materilizer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like your model defines one of the properties as non-nullable, but the database has the corresponding column as nullable, and has a null value in it. When the generated reader attempts to populate the model, BOOM. Unfortunately, we can't tell you which property, and it doesn't need to even be one of those mentioned in that code, since it could be the `FrobNumber` property of whatever `Sales_inv_details` represents.

You need to check your model very carefully. Start with the properties / columns on whatever `Sales_inv_details` represents. When you have found a mismatch: mark it as nullable, and retry.

Comment: I too have got this error sometimes but never understand it why this error comes but now i have got my answer.Thanks for an awesome explanation

Answer (score 2):

One of the properties on one of the Entity classes is defined as `int` (`System.Int32`), but in the database is a `null` value. Since `int` cannot be `null` this error comes up.

To fix this either make sure the database query returns no null values, or change your property definition to a nullable integer (`int?` or `Nullable<int>`).

To find the respective records in your Database try re-creating the query in SQL Management Studio (i.e. setting the same "WHERE filters"), and check the results for empty columns that should contain integer values.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like wrong mapping db fields to the model.
Probably you have `int` property in your model, but `int?` in database

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell without having the entity model, but this exception usually happens when the query involves some `left outer join`, so although LINQ to Entities does not generate NRE if you don't include `null` checks for the right (optional) side, it requires you to promote non nullable value types into nullable inside the projections.

Check some of the following relations: `sales.Sales_Invoices`, `sales.Sales_Invoices.Customer`, `sales.Sales_Invoices.Employe`, `sales.Item`, `sales.Item.TBL_Unit_Measure`. If some of the right end properties are optional, make sure to include cast to the corresponding nullable type in the projection, i.e. if you have `int` property, use `= (int?)..` in the select clause (or C#6 `?.` operator).

P.S. The exception message indicates `Int32`, so concentrate on `int` columns.

Answer (score 0):

Try to handle the null values generated /existing null values by use of

- (int?)
- (p.property == null) ? 0 : p.property